# how to do deep copy with out operator = in class

Tags: c++

```
struct Property 
{
    int objID;
    const char* objName;
};


struct Data
{
    Property propertyRef;
}

std::vector<Data> items;
```

Here one of the function I am assigning data as follows

```
Data d1;
d1.propertyRef.objID = 1;
d1.propertyRef.objName = "MyObj";

//... I am some logic in between and passing this d2 which is mentioned below to another thread in argument

Data d2 = d1;
```

Problem is that when I print `d2.propertyRef.objName` it is printing junk value?

Point here is that I am using library and I cannot change library to add operator = in Data.

Why I am facing this problem and how to solve it? (I googled it, mentioned that I have to deep copy and I am not sure how to d that for vector.

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::string`:

```
std::string objName;
```

Now it will do the job of deep-copy. No need to worry about it anymore.

Also, in general, `std::string` is awesome, you will love it. Use it when you need  `char*` or `const char*` (as a general rule).

Comment: No string class is a *best* friend of Unicode, in any language.

Comment: How about `NSString` in Objective-C?

Comment: Then ask which unicode it is a best friend of? utf-8, utf-16, utf-32, or?

Comment: Well, my only point was that `std::string` is not so awesome as your answer advertises it, that's all.

Comment: @DesmondHume: *Awesome* should be taken in context.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change `Property` to use a `std::string` instead of a `const char*` everything will work.

If you can't, wrap `Data` in a class you *can* provide a copy ctor/assign operator for and store a vector of that.

Comment: how to wrap data in DataRef with three operators?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class DataRef which embeds Data and implement the rule-of-three in that on behalf of the Data/Property. Then use DataRef in the vector.

Comment: can you please give me an example how to do it?

Comment: mm. I misread your question. Your pointer is const char* and you are assigning the address of a string literal. Then the problem which you mentioned cannot come so easily. How do you pass Data object to the thread? Can you please show that code?

Answer (score 0):

First, for the bit of code you show, shallow copy should work.  As long
as `objName` points to a string literal, there should be no problems.

If `objName` does start pointing to other things, then you probably need
special functions to manage it, not just for assignment, but also for
creation, etc.  At this point, you will need a wrapper class.  But
first, I'd ensure that you do need it: since you say that `Data` is in
an external library that you can't change, it might have some
constraints about this as well.  (Does the library copy `Data`
internally?  If so, then you must ensure the lifetime of the string you
pass it, someway or another.)